# Declaring the value_type when implementing an iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, containers

I am implementing an iterator for a custom container in c++11

I get the following error:

```
no type named 'value_type' in 'struct std::iterator_traits<PixBuffer<float>::seq_read_iterator>'
    typedef typename iterator_traits<_OI>::value_type _ValueTypeO;
```

I have read before the answer here:
[How to implement an STL-style iterator and avoid common pitfalls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054273/how-to-implement-an-stl-style-iterator-and-avoid-common-pitfalls)

It states that I can:

- specialize `std::iterator_traits<youriterator>` : This is not the preferred method according to the author, for code readability, as this type declaration is not nested in the class
- Put the same typedefs in the iterator itself : I did this but I still have the error above
- Inherit from std::iterator : will this fix my problem, and what is the proper way to use this method?

This interator works as a back_inserter.
The current class definition is:

```
template<typename T>
class PixBuffer
{
public:
    friend class seq_read_iterator;

    /* container class implementation removed from here */

public:
    class seq_read_iterator
    {
    public:
        typedef T value_type;

        seq_read_iterator(PixBuffer & pb);
        seq_read_iterator & operator*(T val);
        seq_read_iterator & operator++();
        seq_read_iterator operator++(int);
        seq_read_iterator & operator=(T val);

        /* iterator class implementation removed from here */
    };


    seq_read_iterator seqReadIterator() { return seq_read_iterator(*this); }
};
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: "_Put the same typedefs in the iterator itself : I did this but I still have the error above_". It seems like you did it wrongly. Show relevant parts an maybe we could help.

Comment: Regarding "I thought this was forbidden by the standard": `[namespace.std]/1` "A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace `std` only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited."

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot : Code added

Comment: @TartanLlama : you are right, this is valid. I would prefer another method for better code organization, though, if possible.

Comment: The current trend seems to be option 2, add the typedefs to the iterator. That's what the standard document does in later drafts.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/q/29108958/819272

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All 3 posted ways to make iterator work are legal.

Preferred way is to add required type aliases to the class itself. Inheriting from `std::iterator` is just a quick way to do that.

Specializing `std::iterator_traits` is usually used, when you already have a non-conforming iterator, which code you cannot change.

---

Your code does not work because you did not add all 5 required type aliases. Before C++11 it would just explode and complain that it cannot instantiate `iterator_traits`. Now it just creates empty trait class:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits

> If `Iterator` does not have the five member types `difference_type`, `value_type`, `pointer`, `reference`, and `iterator_category`, then this template has no member types (`std::iterator_traits` is SFINAE-friendly)

Comment: Thanks! The gcc error message is quite misleading then